# android set specific rows background of a listview with a color

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I am working on a listview, and would like to higlight, for example, row 3 to row 7 in the listview.

### Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_list);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sample_listview);

    String[] Sample_List = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sample_List);  
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Sample_List.length; ++i) 
    {
        list.add(Sample_List[i]);
    }

    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

## updates:

I have updated the codes as follows:

```
    lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            ... 
        }
    });
}

public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;

      public MyCustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) 
      {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView  (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
      {
          View  view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
          if(position>=3&&position<=7)
          {
              view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_btn);
          }
          else
          {
              view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_btn);
          }  
          return view;
      }
}
```

### Question:

I have researched a lot on the web but I still cannot figure out how to implement that `getView`... in this way how could the above be changed such that for example, background row 3 to 7 to be set in red?

Implemented the updated codes, the listview cannot expand properly to show each item, only item's border can be shown (the green button has some black border), possibly because not linking the list.

How could I connect the list with the MyCustomArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about storing the highlighted positions in a `List`, so that you can do something like this.-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (highlightedPositions.contains(position)) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);
    }
    return view;
}
```

**EDIT**

Now that you have your own custom adapter, replace the code where you're setting the `StableArrayAdapter`.-

```
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with this.-

```
final MyCustomArrayAdapter adapter = new MyCustomArrayAdapter(this, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I can pre-set the position of the row number for those rows to be highlighted, but not quite know how to connect getView and the Adater together

Comment: Two options: create a custom adapter which stores the `List` of highlighted positions, or store the `List` inside the class in which you wrote your `getView` method, and access it with `TheClassContainingGetViewMethod.this.highlightedPositions`

Comment: I have created a custom adapter as updated in the question but still dont know how to connect it with the list...could you offer some advice?

Comment: In the same way you connected the `StableArrayAdapter`. Actually, you won't need it anymore, instantiate your custom adapter instead and pass it to `setAdapter`.

Comment: wow the list is now loaded properly...! but then when pressed it cannot go to the item detailed page as before...

Comment: Mmh did you accidentally remove `setOnItemClickListener` sentence?

Comment: oh! finally it is Runnable!! it is because the string list has strange character and it does not highlight in red until run! Many thanks for your help, ssantos!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution

```
 public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent,
                        false);
                TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner
                        .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
                if(position==1)
                main_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);





                return mySpinner;
            }
```

Item at postion 1 will have green color